# Concatenate byte array and int value in java

Tags: java, int, concatenation, byte

Is there a way to concatenate byte array and int value in java. Any help is appreciated. All I could find was concatenating 2 arrays.

int res=somefunction(byte[] buf,..);
now i want to concatenate the buf and the res.
I can use String[] instead of byte[] if needed.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Can you please give some examples?

Comment: Can you post some code for context?

Comment: what is your input + expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] buf = ...;
int res = somefunction(buf); 
byte[] buf2 = new byte[buf.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(buf, 0, buf2, 0, buf.length);
buf2[buf.length] = (byte)res;
buf = buf2;
```